# FIO generating empty files when run through subprocess

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

I'm having an issue when running FIO through subprocess.

When running FIO with the option --bandwidth-log the created file (agg-read_bw.log) is empty when the command is run through subprocess.The FIO command is run using the following subprocess call:

```
cmd_stat = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
```

If I run the exact string through the command prompt then the files are generated and populated correctly. In both cases the FIO job completes successfully.

This is on Ubuntu 18.04, python 2.7.17, FIO version 3.16.

Edit: Tried on Python 3.6 with the same result

Here's an example of a command that exhibits this behavior:
fio --filename=/dev/sda2 --readwrite=read --size=1g --name=bw_test --bandwidth-log

Comment: It would help to know how long your job took to run when you were running it by hand and when you were running it via python. If for some reason the cache invalidation wasn't successful (maybe you've got a filesystem mounted of `/dev/sda2` locking the pages in which case please BE CAREFUL - doing fio tests on block devices that contain data you can't afford to be destroyed is RISKY and not recommend as one slip and DATA is IRRETRIEVABLY GONE) you may find yourself doing reads that are satisfied by the kernel cache and those can complete _extremely_ quickly...

Comment: Hi, did the answer below explain your situation? If so could you accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using the `--bandwidth-log` option samples I/O over a period specified by [`bwavgtime`](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-arg-bwavgtime) which defaults to 500 milliseconds (curiously, `--bandwidth-log` is a command line option whereas `bwavgtime` is a per job option). Given you're not setting `bwavgtime`, if your job doesn't run for at least half a second then by the time it exits no "bandwidth log" samples will have been taken and the bandwidth log files will be empty.